# groupby() with multiple categorical columns delivers unexpected rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I faced an important issue while using `groupby()` with multiple columns of type `'categorical'`. In this scenario, **Pandas delivers unexpected rows**, especially rows that are not delivered with other types. Below is a basic working example.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(['a','a','b','c'], columns=['C1'], dtype='category')
df['C2'] = pd.Series(['x','y','z','y']).astype('category')
df['V'] = 0
df
```

gives a basic `DataFrame`:

```
    C1  C2  V
0   a   x   0
1   a   y   0
2   b   z   0
3   c   y   0
```

Now if group this dataframe with multiple columns:

```py
df.groupby(['C1','C2']).sum()
```

The result contains unexpected rows (combinations of `C1` and `C2` that don't exist in the input dataframe):

```
        V
C1  C2  
a   x   0
    y   0
    z   0
b   x   0
    y   0
    z   0
c   x   0
    y   0
    z   0
```

If we convert `'categorical'` columns to `string` types

```py
df[['C1','C2']] = df[['C1','C2']].astype(str)
df.groupby(['C1','C2']).sum()
```

The result contains only expected rows:

```
        V
C1  C2  
a   x   0
    y   0
b   z   0
c   y   0
```

Is there any other way, than converting categorical columns to string, to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

@wjandrea suggested a working solution: an extra parameter `observed=True` passed to `groupby()`:

```py
df.groupby(['C1','C2'], observed=True).sum()
```

Result is delivered as expected:

```
        V
C1  C2  
a   x   0
    y   0
b   z   0
c   y   0
```

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing solutions. There's a banner on top of your question where you can click the option something like "Yes, this answers my question."